# Question regarding the Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let ${f: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf C}}$ be an absolutely integrable function, and let ${\lambda > 0}$. Given the One-sided Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality:

$\displaystyle m( \{ x \in {\bf R}: \sup_{h>0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{[x,x+h]} |f(t)|\ dt \geq \lambda \} ) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{\bf R} |f(t)|\ dt$.

Show the Two-sided Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality:

$\displaystyle m( \{ x \in {\bf R}: \sup_{x \in I} \frac{1}{|I|} \int_{I} |f(t)|\ dt \geq \lambda \} ) \leq \frac{2}{\lambda} \int_{\bf R} |f(t)|\ dt$,

where the supremum ranges over all intervals ${I}$ of positive length that contain ${x}$. Can we do this by simply using the one-sided result on the reflected function $x \rightarrow f(-x)$?

Comment: I don’t think that transformation will do what you want. Perhaps considering $y=x-h$, you can split up the two sided into two one sided integrals.

Comment: @Nick But then you will be dealing with an uncountable family of the shifted functions $g_h(x) = f(x - h)$, rather than the single function $f$ to which the one-sided result applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this more in line with what you were thinking: Consider the maximal operator $$M_- f(x):= \sup_{h>0} \dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x-h}^{x} |f|\, dx,$$
and with $M_+$ denoting your one-sided maximal operator. Then we have
$$
M_- f(x)= (M_+ f_1) (-x), \qquad \text{where} f_1(y):= f(-y).
$$
In particular, $M_-$ satisfies the same estimate as $M_+$.
Now use (and prove!) that if $M$ denotes your second (uncentered) maximal function, then $$\{x: Mf(x)>\lambda\}\subset  \{ x: M_+f(x)>\lambda\} \cup \{ x: M_-f(x)>\lambda\}.$$
Note that this inclusion is not "trivial", as using the easy estimate $Mf(x)\leq M_+f(x)+M_-f(x)$ yields a factor of $\lambda/2$ instead of $\lambda$ in both terms on the right of the display (this gives a factor of 4 for the uncentered bound, instead of 2). The point is that the easy inequality can be improved by controlling $1/|I|\int_I |f|$ by an *average* of $M_\pm f(x)$ for any $x\in I$.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve the problem a week ago. After establishing the left maximal inequality, the triangle inequality will do the rest of the work.

Comment: By the way, how does one show that $Mf \leq 1/2(M_{-}f + M_{+}f)$?

Comment: @爸爸到底: That inequality is not true (think for instance $f=1_{[0,1]}$ then $Mf(x)=M_+f(x)$, $M_-f(x)=0$ for $x<0$).

Comment: Got it. Can you elaborate then of your last comment about improving the easy inequality?

Comment: @爸爸到底: When I say " the easy inequality can be improved" I mean as far as getting $\lambda$ in place of $\lambda/2$ in the last display. So we're not really getting a better pointwise inequality, but rather a better way of controlling the size of the set where $Mf>\lambda$. Perhaps it'd be clearer if I'd written "the estimate/set inclusion you get from the easy inequality can be improved by..."

Comment: It is clear that $M_\pm f(x) > \lambda$ implies that $Mf(x) > \lambda$, what I'm not sure about is the other direction.

Comment: @爸爸到底: The idea is that, if $a,b,c\geq 0$, and if $a\leq \alpha b +(1-\alpha)c$ for some $\alpha\in [0,1]$, then $a>\lambda$ implies either $b>\lambda$ or $c>\lambda$. In our case $\alpha$ will depend on $x$, and so we don't quite get a (uniform) pointwise inequality, but something good enough to get the inclusion I mention.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Mimic the proof of the one-sided inequality. As you construct the function $F(x) = \int_{[a, x]} |f(t)| dt - (x-a) \lambda$, the condition $\sup_{x \in I} \frac{1}{|I|} \int_I |f(t)| dt > \lambda$ can be rewritten as

$$
\exists h, k>0: F(x-k) < F(x+h)
$$

In what way can you split this into two cases that each can be reduced to the proof of one-sided case?

**Further hint**: How does $F(x)$ compare with $F(x-k)$ and $F(x+h)$? What cases are there?